# How to get recently updated records in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get recently updated records from a sqlite database. Here is my table structure.

```
_id      BookName       BookPath
 1       Book Title     Path
 2       Book Title     Path
```

I want to know which books user read recently.
If there is no exact way is available please tell me any logic to achieve it. I can also add more columns if needed to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know which books user read recently. If there is no exact way is available please tell me any logic to achieve it

Store last read time stamp in book's record, then you will be able to figure this out or query with date based order. Otherwise it may be rather tricky without crystal ball, as there's no data to get this info from in your current table structure.

Comment: Thanks. This means when user open any book I have to first check if book already exist in table. And if it exist then I should update its time stamp.

Comment: If user can open non existing book then yes, otherwise you got book's id already (as s/he just opened it) and issue regular `UPDATE`

Answer (score 0):

In your database, create a new column, and when the user reads a book, store the timestamp in your new column, and when you want to get the list of last read books, sort your database query by that timestamp.

Not hard really!